# How to use pricing service in Spartacus design

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have a scinario where the price calculation happens at realtime by calling external service.

Coming to Spartacus, what would be the best approach.

Writing custom service to make realtime call for getting pricing data and use(call) the service in Spartacus.
Calling the external service with required parameters from Spartacus storefront.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should create a service, that uses your newly created NGRX store (actions, effects, reducer etc..) and your own connector / adapter to call your external API. Then you can subscribe to the state changes to render the response when your the data is received.

I guess with realtime, you mean something that is calculated on an event, or is it something you need to stream / call every x seconds?

Comment: if you don't want to overcomplicate things, you don't really have to create a NGRX store, but this is common practice if you have a lot of different endpoints for the external API. In this case you would just create a service, that uses angular httpclient and return an observable with your data

Comment: Hi @Eric Slagter, yes real time means calling the price service while updating Cart.

Comment: @BadriNath I think you can setup an event that triggers on the CartAddEntrySuccessEvent to recalculate the prices https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/event-service/#page-title